# After making payment not able to redirect on relay url

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, authorize.net

I am making the payment using authorize.net weblink "https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll" on the sharepoint page.

After filling in the information and making the payment it doest not redirect the page on `x_relay_url`. Instead, it shows the error of "Sorry something went wrong" as below.

[image]

I tried to make the payment using sandbox account. it makes the payment transaction however after transaction it does not redirect on URL instead it shows the error.

```
var fingerprint1;
var amount1 = "95.00";
$(document).ready(function(){
});
function setFormAction(button) {    
    var theForm = $(button).parents('form:first')[0];

    //sandbox 
    var loginid = "99NSdk8a"
    var txnkey = "9s54MPz333NcVUm5"


    //Randomize
    var sequence = parseInt(1000 * Math.random());
    var tstamp = GetSecondsSince1970 ()
//added for student rate--CHANGE THIS TO USE VARIABLES SET AT PAGE LOAD
    if (theForm.student.checked) {
        amount1 = "0.05";
    } else {amount1 = "95.00"}

//  set form action
    if (theForm.payment_type[0].checked){
        //theForm.action = "https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";
        theForm.action = "https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";
        theForm.method="POST"
    } else {
        theForm.action = "http://trainingcenter.umaryland.edu/SaveRegistrations/save_registrationSuicidePrevention2019.aspx";
    }

//  set amount and fingerprint
    theForm.x_amount.value = amount1;
    theForm.x_fp_hash.value = fingerprint1;

  theForm.submit();
  return (true);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the full error message?

Comment: added screenshot in question